# Identifying and removing invalid time steps in a pandas time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, python-xarray

I looked for an answer for this for a while but haven't been able to find anything, so forgive me if this question has been asked before...

I have some 6-hourly timeseries data `future` of future temperature projections for the years 2031-2050. Upon looking at the data, I notice that there is some faulty timedeltas in the dataset starting at `future.iloc[234]`:

```
future.iloc[220:281]

        time                    Temp
220     2031-03-28 00:00:00     68.276657
221     2031-03-28 06:00:00     68.270706
222     2031-03-28 12:00:00     68.264748
223     2031-03-28 18:00:00     68.258781
224     2031-03-29 00:00:00     68.252808
225     2031-03-29 06:00:00     68.246849
226     2031-03-29 12:00:00     68.240883
227     2031-03-29 18:00:00     68.234909
228     2031-03-30 00:00:00     68.228943
229     2031-03-30 06:00:00     68.222984
230     2031-03-30 12:00:00     68.217010
231     2031-03-30 18:00:00     68.211052
232     2031-03-31 00:00:00     68.205093
233     2031-03-31 06:00:00     68.199120
234     2031-03-31 12:00:00     68.193153
235     2031-02-26 00:00:00     68.187195
236     2031-02-26 06:00:00     68.181236
237     2031-02-26 12:00:00     68.175270
238     2031-02-26 18:00:00     68.169304
239     2031-02-27 00:00:00     68.163322
240     2031-02-27 06:00:00     68.169304
....
369     2031-03-31 12:00:00     68.193153
370     2031-03-31 18:00:00     68.258781
371     2031-04-01 00:00:00     67.950096
372     2031-04-01 06:00:00     67.949493
373     2031-04-01 12:00:00     67.949539
374     2031-04-01 18:00:00     67.950241
375     2031-04-02 00:00:00     67.951591
376     2031-04-02 06:00:00     67.953590
377     2031-04-02 12:00:00     67.955589
378     2031-04-02 18:00:00     67.957596
379     2031-04-03 00:00:00     67.959595
380     2031-04-03 06:00:00     67.961601
```

The dataset continues with the correct timedelta after this blip, but seems to repeat just over a whole month of data (i.e. `future.iloc[370] = 2031-03-31 18:00:00` which should be the next timestep after `future.iloc[234]`, and continues with valid data from this point on).I know that the data (other than the repeated month) is valid, so I need to try an salvage the data if I can. I have a number of these datasets, so I now fear that they may have faulty time steps in them as well.

My goal is to check for an inconsistent timedelta between two points, and either remove the rows with the invalid timedeltas:

```
        time                    Temp
220     2031-03-28 00:00:00     68.276657
221     2031-03-28 06:00:00     68.270706
222     2031-03-28 12:00:00     68.264748
223     2031-03-28 18:00:00     68.258781
224     2031-03-29 00:00:00     68.252808
225     2031-03-29 06:00:00     68.246849
226     2031-03-29 12:00:00     68.240883
227     2031-03-29 18:00:00     68.234909
228     2031-03-30 00:00:00     68.228943
229     2031-03-30 06:00:00     68.222984
230     2031-03-30 12:00:00     68.217010
231     2031-03-30 18:00:00     68.211052
232     2031-03-31 00:00:00     68.205093
233     2031-03-31 06:00:00     68.199120
234     2031-03-31 12:00:00     68.193153
235     2031-03-31 18:00:00     68.258781
236     2031-04-01 00:00:00     67.950096
237     2031-04-01 06:00:00     67.949493
238     2031-04-01 12:00:00     67.949539
239     2031-04-01 18:00:00     67.950241
240     2031-04-02 00:00:00     67.951591
241     2031-04-02 06:00:00     67.953590
242     2031-04-02 12:00:00     67.955589
243     2031-04-02 18:00:00     67.957596
244     2031-04-03 00:00:00     67.959595
245     2031-04-03 06:00:00     67.961601
```

or null all data that is associated with an invalid timedelta:

```
        time                    Temp
220     2031-03-28 00:00:00     68.276657
221     2031-03-28 06:00:00     68.270706
222     2031-03-28 12:00:00     68.264748
223     2031-03-28 18:00:00     68.258781
224     2031-03-29 00:00:00     68.252808
225     2031-03-29 06:00:00     68.246849
226     2031-03-29 12:00:00     68.240883
227     2031-03-29 18:00:00     68.234909
228     2031-03-30 00:00:00     68.228943
229     2031-03-30 06:00:00     68.222984
230     2031-03-30 12:00:00     68.217010
231     2031-03-30 18:00:00     68.211052
232     2031-03-31 00:00:00     68.205093
233     2031-03-31 06:00:00     68.199120
234     2031-03-31 12:00:00     68.193153
235     2031-02-26 00:00:00     NaN
236     2031-02-26 06:00:00     NaN
237     2031-02-26 12:00:00     NaN
238     2031-02-26 18:00:00     NaN
239     2031-02-27 00:00:00     NaN
240     2031-02-27 06:00:00     NaN
....
369     2031-03-31 12:00:00     NaN
370     2031-03-31 18:00:00     68.258781
371     2031-04-01 00:00:00     67.950096
372     2031-04-01 06:00:00     67.949493
373     2031-04-01 12:00:00     67.949539
374     2031-04-01 18:00:00     67.950241
375     2031-04-02 00:00:00     67.951591
376     2031-04-02 06:00:00     67.953590
377     2031-04-02 12:00:00     67.955589
378     2031-04-02 18:00:00     67.957596
379     2031-04-03 00:00:00     67.959595
380     2031-04-03 06:00:00     67.961601
```

The real problem I can't fully wrap my head around is that *only* `future.iloc[235]` is an invalid timedelta. `future.iloc[236:270]` are still technically correct 6H timesteps, they have just been offset, which causes the duplication. So to fully remove invalid data, I need to identify **both the invalid timedelta as well as the valid timedeltas that create the duplicate data**.

I have attempted to create a comparison date range with `pd.date_range(start=future.iloc[0].time, end=future.iloc[-1].time, freq='6H')`, and iterate through my rows to find faulty values. However, I have not been able to come up with a solution that will actually  identify and remove the faulty rows.

Any ideas on how to do this? I assumed pandas would have some built-in functionality for something like this, but haven't been able to find anything substantial that fits my needs.

**Bonus**: Every check that I have tried seems to take up to minute to run through about 30,000 rows of data. Does this number of rows warrant this time usage iterate through?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "remove the faulty rows, or null all data that is associated with these rows"? When an inconsistent timedelta is found, you want something like removing rows with dates on the same day ?

Comment: @jmiguel Yes, as well as any data associated with the invalid timedelta. I added some info to my question that will hopefully clarify this further.

Answer (score 0):

to identify the errors maybe to do this sort of test:

1) you group by day
2) you trap the group with number items > 0 and < 4
3) you have the list of errors, you could drop the corresponding rows

```
errorlist=[]
def f(g):
    if g.shape[0] > 0 and g.shape[0] < 4:
        errorlist.append(g.index[0])
df.set_index('time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(f)

print(errorlist)
```